# Pushing to multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble pushing to a multi-dim array, I get the error

> _this.fieldRefs[ID].push is not a function

My code is quite simple, so I thought:

```
this.fieldRefs = this.fieldRefs || []; // init `this.fieldRefs` if it doesn't exist
this.fieldRefs.push(ID); // push the `ID` e.g `0`
this.fieldRefs[ID].push(ref); // add the `ref` to `0` (ref is an ele)
```

The first two lines work correctly, and `this.fieldRefs` contains `ID` e.g:

```
this.fieldRefs = [0]
```

But the final line is where the error occurs. If I check `this.fieldRefs[ID]` I do indeed get `0` but I cannot push to `0` index

Comment: this.fieldRefs[ID] = [] should be initialized as push works on array type

Comment: You're trying to `.push` something into the number `0`…?!

Comment: @evolutionxbox JS has multi-dimensional array!! The "object" is another thing.

Comment: What you want to do is to assign an array of refs related to an ID. so if ID will always be a number, instead of pushing this value to an existing array, it would be a better idea to initialize an array in the index defined by that ID. Like this: `this.fieldRefs = this.fieldRefs || []; this.fieldRefs[ID] = []; this.fieldRefs[ID].push(ref)`. What you are doing currently is different, since you are storing the values of ID on consecutive indices in your `fieldRefs` array, but the indices don't match the ID values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is to assign an array of refs related to an ID.

So if ID will always be a number, instead of pushing this value to an existing array, it would be a better idea to initialize an array in the index defined by that ID. Like this:

```
this.fieldRefs = this.fieldRefs || []; 
this.fieldRefs[ID] = []; 
this.fieldRefs[ID].push(ref).
```

What you are doing currently is different, since you are storing the values of ID on consecutive indices in your `fieldRefs` array, but the indices don't match the ID values.